# Raster info in rasterio module

Tags: qgis, python, statistics, rasterio

I have a folder of NDVI rasters and I want to see their stats as follows:

```
with rasterio.open('C:\\path_to_NDVI.tif', 'r+') as ds:
    array=ds.read()

    stats = []

    for band in array:
        stats.append({
            'min': band.min(),
            'mean': band.mean(),
            'median': np.median(band),
            'max': band.max()})
    
    stats

[{'min': -32768, 'mean': -3250.0849086875, 'median': 1547.0, 'max': 9994}]
```

The problem is that checking on QGIS the data does not match, in fact on QGIS the image data are:

```
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=9272    
STATISTICS_MEAN=2820.9099057427    
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-6171    
STATISTICS_STDDEV=2201.6453582856
```

Having a nodata value `-32768.0` might be the problem? How can I get the same statistics as QGIS?

---

It doesn't really match QGIS, how come?

```
Band 1 Block=4000x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=-6939.000 Max=9994.000   Computed Min/Max=-6939.000,9994.000
  Minimum=-6939.000, Maximum=9994.000, Mean=2822.344, StdDev=2204.594
  NoData Value=-32768
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=9994
    STATISTICS_MEAN=2822.3440402538
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-6939
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=2204.5942196929
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=82.94
```

---

I get this when I try your suggestion:

```
array[array == ds.nodata] = np.nan

arr_min = np.nanmin(array)


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-9ad870d738e7> in <module>
----> 1 array[array == ds.nodata] = np.nan
      2 
      3 arr_min = np.nanmin(array)

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

While when I use the other option the numbers still don't match:

```
m = (array != ds.nodata)
arr_min = array[m].min()

print('min=',array[m].min())
print('mean =%.2f'%array[m].mean())
print('max=',array[m].max())
print('std =%.2f'%array[m].std())

min= -6939
mean =2822.34
max= 9994
std =2204.59
```

Comment: You have NODATA values. What does `ds.nodata` or `band.nodata` say?

Comment: ds.nodata = -32768.0

Comment: NaN is a float so that approach won't work for integer rasters.  Use `gdalinfo -mm` to see what gdal thinks the range is.  If it matches what numpy says then the stats written into the image metadata are out of date and need to be recalculated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodata value is being considered when computing the statistics, as you've found.  So either replace it with `np.nan` and use stats [functions that are NaN-aware](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.statistics.html):

```
array[array == ds.nodata] = np.nan

arr_min = np.nanmin(array)
```

Or mask off the nodata values and compute the stats off of that:

```
m = (array != ds.nodata)

arr_min = array[m].min()
```